# Unique string confusion mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my table

```
id       some_column           store_id                  
1         (Excl. Tax)             1
2         (Incl. Tax)             1
3         Target Rule/Product     1       
4         File %1 does not exist  1         
5         hello                   1
6         hello                   2 <--- valid because store_id is 2 If its 1 then it should invalid as I want unique string for each store

...
```

Where `id` is auto increment and primary key, `some_column` has varchar and it has `unique constraint` and `store_id` is id of my store(it can be 1 or 2 or 3 and so on)

In this table everything is works but when I have store_id has 2 and and at that time I am adding same string which has store_id 1 then it gives me  unique constraint violation found error. But I want to avoid this error as this has different store_id. so how can I achieve this? Any idea on this?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `comment_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `test_text` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Test String',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `translation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Modification Time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`store_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CUSTOMER_TEST_TEXT` (`test_text`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='comment_data';
```

Comment: Please Show the ddl of your table

Comment: Look at a composite key like `PRIMARY KEY (some_column, store_id)`

Comment: Updated my question @Jens

Comment: Could you please elaborate @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the unique constraint to *both* the `some_column` and `store_id` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD UNIQUE u_idx (some_column, store_id);
```

If you already have a unique constraint on `some_column`, then you might have to drop that first:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP INDEX old_idx;
```

Comment: Yes, I already have unique key at `some_column` but want to confirm now `store_id` is also foreign key of my another table , so is it ok? Thanks a lot for answer

Comment: Your sample table data imply that `some_column` is _not_ unique, but that the combination of `some_column` and `store_id` together should be unique.  My answer addresses this.  As to whether `store_id` is a foreign key into some other table, this design decision is up to you.  If you want to make it a foreign key, then go ahead and do it.